# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Using JUCE And Heavy-Compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, puredata, juce

I am currently writing a super basic plugin using the JUCE framework and C code generated from a the [Heavy Pure Data Online Compiler](https://enzienaudio.com/). The source code builds fine, however no standalone application, AudioUnit or VST are created by Xcode. My guess is that the project is not setup properly to use the included code, however I am still learning my way around Xcode and can't seem to work out what the problem is to fix the below errors. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Edit: Finally started using git and uploaded the project to GitHub [here](https://github.com/J-Bledsoe/TestingHeavy.git).

Comment: make your project available, so one can check whats going on or give a much more detailed description.

Comment: I'm relatively new to posting on Stack Exchange, is there a recommended way of making the project available to you?

Comment: I´m relatively new too :-) I´ve seen git very often, its free.

Comment: Just started on using git, so ignore any problems on that side of things. I've uploaded the project to here [GitHub Project](https://github.com/J-Bledsoe/TestingHeavy.git) and edited the original post to include the project too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projucer file you included is missing the heavy source folder. Add them in projucer on the left side in the file explorer area (right click in the file area on source and choose add existing files...

Hint the `save and open in ide` icon on top of the window

and there you go ... no linker error.

tested with XCode 8.3.3

Two remarks:

- Never add files anywhere else than in projucer
- You can´t use XCode 9 beta with JUCE

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple thing to miss. Why is it that the file needs to be added to the projucer project to and not just included?